# AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: record, line 3 - - - Odoo13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to add a menu under `Actions`. But i am getting below error.

> 2019-12-24 11:28:28,309 22740 ERROR odoo13 werkzeug: Error on request:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line
>   270, in run_wsgi
>       execute(self.server.app)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line
>   258, in execute
>       application_iter = app(environ, start_response)   File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/service/server.py", line 414,
>   in app
>       return self.app(e, s)   File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line
>   142, in application
>       return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)   File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line
>   117, in application_unproxied
>       result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)   File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/http.py", line 1281, in
>   **call**
>       return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)   File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/http.py", line 1251, in
>   **call**
>       return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 766,
>   in **call**
>       return self.app(environ, start_response)   File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/http.py", line 1433, in
>   dispatch
>       odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()   File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/**init**.py", line 104, in
>   registry
>       return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)   File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 61,
>   in **new**
>       return cls.new(db_name)   File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 85,
>   in new
>       odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)   File
>   "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 416,
>   in load_modules
>       force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)   File
>   "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 312,
>   in load_marked_modules
>       perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check   File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/modules/loading.py", line
>   222, in load_module_graph
>       load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)   File
>   "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 68,
>   in load_data
>       tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)   File
>   "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 737, in
>   convert_file
>       convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)   File "/home/user/Projects/odoo_13.0.EE/odoo/tools/convert.py", line
>   787, in convert_xml_import
>       relaxng.assert_(doc)   File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3536, in lxml.etree.*Validator.assert*
>   AssertionError: Element odoo has extra
>   content: record, line 3 - - -

***.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <odoo>
    <record id="import_image_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">import.image.form</field>
      <field name="model">import.image</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Import Images">
          <group >
              <field widget="binary" height="64" name="file" filename="file_fname" required="1"/>
              <field name="file_fname" invisible="1"/>
          </group>

          <footer>
            <button name="get_file" type="object" class="oe_highlight" string="Load File" style="width:75px;"/>
            <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
          </footer>
        </form>
      </field>
    </record>
    <record id="import_image_action_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
      <field name="name">Import product images</field>
      <field name="res_model">import.image</field>
      <field name="view_mode">form</field>
      <field name="view_id" ref="import_image_view_form"/>
      <field name="target">new</field>
    </record>

      <act_window
        name="Import Product Image"
        id="action_import_product_image"
        res_model="import.image"
        src_model="product.template"
        target="new" multi="True" key2="client_action_multi"/>

  </odoo>
```

Comment: You can have this error when you miss spell a tag or add some content accidentally. just comment the records and witch one is causing the problem. I use this technique specially when I cant see the errors like in your case

Comment: Actually the `<act_window/>` tag is causing the error. When i comment it working fine. I copy-paste the line from odoo default module, still same error.

Comment: Got it. You are not passing `view_mode` parameter in action. I have updated my answer you can try it.

Comment: @MayurJotaniya, I tried `view_mode`, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, i found a solution. I just removed`act_window` tag. And added a field `binding_model_id` in `ir.actions.act_window`.

```xml
<record id="import_image_action_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Import product images</field>
  <field name="res_model">import.image</field>
  <field name="view_mode">form</field>
  <field name="view_id" ref="import_image_view_form"/>
  <field name="target">new</field>
  <field name="binding_model_id" ref="account.model_product_template" />
</record>
```

it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned `<data>` in your `xml` code. I have updated it. Please try below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <record id="import_image_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
          <field name="name">import.image.form</field>
          <field name="model">import.image</field>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Import Images">
              <group >
                  <field widget="binary" height="64" name="file" filename="file_fname" required="1"/>
                  <field name="file_fname" invisible="1"/>
              </group>

              <footer>
                <button name="get_file" type="object" class="oe_highlight" string="Load File" style="width:75px;"/>
                <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
              </footer>
            </form>
          </field>
        </record>

        <record id="import_image_action_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
          <field name="name">Import product images</field>
          <field name="res_model">import.image</field>
          <field name="view_mode">form</field>
          <field name="view_id" ref="import_image_view_form"/>
          <field name="target">new</field>
        </record>

        <act_window 
            name="Import Product Image"
            res_model="import.image"
            src_model="product.template"
            view_mode="form"
            target="new"
            multi="True"
            key2="client_action_multi"
            id="action_import_product_image" />
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

**main issue is basically XML tags misspell which shows the Assertion Error**

```
    <munuitem id="menu_student_list" parent="menu_student_list" name="Atten" action="action_student_detail_tree" />

    <menuitem id="menu_student_list" parent="menu_student_list" name="Atten" action="action_student_detail_tree" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).